# How to fix 'radio button value doesn't save in database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have 12 radio buttons. When I click submit, the variable of POST method is empty, I was trying to use get method but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="q2">
    <h4 class="info-text"> يرحب بالمناقشة ويتقبل وجهة النظر الاخرى من الطلبة</h4>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="choice" data-toggle="question2">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="qqq2" value="1">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>نعم</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="choice" data-toggle="question2">
                    <input type="radio" name="qqq2" class="form-control" value="2">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-hand-paper-o"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>نوعاً ما</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="choice" data-toggle="question2">
                    <input type="radio" name="qqq2" class="form-control" value="3">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>لا</h4>enter code here
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code of php

```
if (isset($_POST['finish'])) {
    $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
    $q1 = $_POST['question'];
    $q2 = $_POST['qqq2'];
    $q3 = $_POST['qqq3'];
    $q4 = $_POST['qqq4'];
    $q5 = $_POST['qqq5'];
    $q6 = $_POST['qqq6'];
    $q7 = $_POST['qqq7'];
    $q8 = $_POST['qqq8'];
    $q9 = $_POST['qqq9'];
    $q10 = $_POST['qqq10'];
    $q11 = $_POST['qqq11'];
    $q12 = $_POST['qqq12'];

    echo $inSql = "INSERT INTO `quesAnswers`( `barcode`, `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`, `q5`, `q6`, `q7`, `q8`, `q9`, `q10`, `q11`, `q12`)
        values ( '$barcode', '$q1', '$q2', '$q3', '$q4', '$q5', '$q6', '$q7', '$q8', '$q9', '$q10', '$q11', '$q12') ";

    $inQuery = mysqli_query($con, $inSql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Change each name="qqq2" to name="qqq2[]" the data will be placed into an array in which you can access by $_POST['qqq2']

Comment: RADIO BUTTON IS USED FOR SELECTING ONLY ONE VALUE OUT OF11.

Comment: AND YOU CAN GET IT BY NAME $q2 = $_POST['qqq2'];

Comment: please provide the `<form ...>` usage & how the `'finish'` element you're checking is implemented ?